# How to do a selective color adjustment in RawTherapee?

Tags: post-processing, selective-color, rawtherapee

GIMP has a nice [color dialog](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tool-hue-saturation.html) that lets me change saturation for certain colors easily.

[image: Gimp Color dialog]

How can I do something similar in Rawtherapee? For quality and consistency reasons I want to stay in one and that program. But even after reading [the manual](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DHLb_6xNQsEInxiuU8pz1-sWNinnj09bpBUA4_Vl8w8/edit) I didn't manage to influence e.g. the cyan value as easily as here. Even if not as easily I didn't manage to do something similar at all.

I am not trained in graphics software in particular, maybe I am just missing something in terminology. But of course I tried the available tools like the RGB curves but nothing seemed to work as specific as e.g changing the saturation of a specific color.

So what is a good way to do this (selective color influence, e.g. change only the saturation of cyan in a certain small range) in Rawtherapee?

Comment: Related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/does-gimp-have-a-match-color-function-similar-to-that-in-adobe-photoshop-cs3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possibilities- "Lab Adjustments" on the Exposure tab, or "HSV Equalizer" on the Color tab.

Comment: Thank you! I don't see how I can do exactly this with the Lab Adjustments but the HSV Equalizer is indeed the exact (and better) equivalent.