# Color correction by a reference image, or How to compare images and generate color lookup table?

Tags: post-processing, software, color-correction

I have two images A and B, of the same object. A has distorted color, but the color of B is better. I want to correct the color of A with the help of information contained in B. How do I do this?

I am an ImageMagick fan, but also appreciate GIMP or any other tools.

I think the process should be first compare and establish a mapping between the two sets of colors, and then apply the mapping to A. The second step is straightforward utilizing the Color LUT "lookup table" with ImageMagick. But I don't find a clue of the comparing step.

While B is good in color, it may be bad in resolution. Otherwise I should just keep B and throw A to the trash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Gimp have a Match Color function similar to that in Adobe Photoshop CS3+?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/does-gimp-have-a-match-color-function-similar-to-that-in-adobe-photoshop-cs3)

Comment: Are the two photos of identical size and geometry? That is, same lens, same framing, same distance to subject etc.  In that case, you can combine the luminance of A with the color channels (LAB or HSV) of B.

Comment: @mattdm That is exactly what i meant . Thanks . I just didn't know the correct google keyword before i asked this question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way is to work channel by channel. Put your images next to each other or in a split view. Then activate only the red channel. You can then adjust the curve for the red channel until the two grayscale images match up. Do the same for the green and blue channels.

This way you have created a 2D LUT.

Comment: Having three separate 1D LUTs may help partway, but isn't going to deal well with the case of different cameras, different sensors, different light sources. Metamerism, nonmatching sensor responses, all that.