# What is the easiest way to alter white balance in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, white-balance

Let's say I've accidentally shot my pictures on "sunny" white balace when I should have used "shade". What is the easiest way to warm the pictures up a bit in Gimp? The "Colors/Color balance" tool does not really cut it, as I don't want to mess with three sliders for three brightness levels.

Comment: Related, but no Gimp answers: [How do I correct white balance in JPEG images?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/how-do-i-correct-white-balance-in-jpeg-images)

Comment: And ditto: [How can I fix the color of blue photos using settings from “good” photos?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The quickest GIMP tool I'm aware of is the `Colors → Levels…` tool. **Near the bottom of the tool are four buttons:** `Auto, Pick black point, Pick gray point, and Pick white point`. You can use the auto (iffy, but it may get it right or close for minor adjustment) or use the white point button to select the white point in the image.

It is, by the way, the same technique I suggested for Photoshop in the first link @mattdm supplied.

Comment: This works for making WB neutral, but what I was hoping for was a tool that would allow me to apply equivalent of (let's say) 1/4 CTO filter. Like a slider with full CTO to neutral to full CTB scale. I guess I'll have to create presets...

Comment: @che - You may want to consider some preset overlays in the various filter colors that you can then tweak the opacity on as you need. Just a thought, it's very similar to how photoshop does these filter sets.

Comment: I got "CTO" and "CTB" gel colors from Rosco's site (252,183,114 and 53,157,218 in RGB colors, if anyone's interested) and this seems to work quite well. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Happy to have helped!